# Transferring Cloud Custodian output json file to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, cloudcustodian

I have a requirement. I am using [CloudCustodian](https://github.com/cloud-custodian/cloud-custodian) to get resources metadata in dev environment. I created one sample `policy.yml` file for EC2 like below:

```
policies:
  - name: my-first-policy
    resource: ec2
```

When I run this command from a ec2:

```
custodian run --dryrun -s . policy.yml
```

I can see in the root directory one directory has been created with "my-first-policy". In this directory there is one file `resource.json` which includes all the details for EC2 instance. I want to send this file to s3 whenever I run cloud custodian command. How can I do this from command line?

Is there any policy that can be written which would transfer the resource.json file to S3 whenever I run the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply the S3 bucket as a value to the `-s` / `--output-dir` argument

```
custodian run --dryrun -s s3://mys3bucketpath policy.yml
```

Then you can see the output stored in s3 directly

```
aws s3 ls s3://mys3bucketpath
```

References:

- https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/aws/usage.html#s3-logs-records

Comment: @PrantikPariksha if this solution helped you, please mark it as the chosen solution. :)